# Update database table where value = 0

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Don't know why I'm getting stumped on something so small,

but I want to update a chunk of data already in my database.

I want to update table `results` and change all values in the 'test1' column where currently value is 0 and set it to NULL for all entries.

can someone help me with the code I need to run this in phpmyadmin.

Comment: `UPDATE results SET test1=null WHERE test1=0`?

Answer (score 6):

```
update results set test1 = null where test1 = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE results SET test1=null WHERE test1=0
```